# AWS KSM Data Key Caching SDK for .NET

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-kms, aws-sdk-net

I'm trying to implement Data Key Caching for AWS on .NET. I've seen that Java has an implementation of [LocalCryptoMaterialsCache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/sample-cache-example.html) which I cannot find for C#. The ideia is to use this so I can send less request to KMS when inserting or retrieving an object from S3.

I was just wondering is anyone was able to achieve this?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such class for C# yet, because that class is part of the [AWS Encryption SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/introduction.html), and that SDK is only (currently) provided in Java and Python ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/programming-languages.html)). If you're feeling adventurous, though, the code is [public and on Github](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-encryption-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/encryptionsdk/caching/LocalCryptoMaterialsCache.java).